# How to associate a type with a generic function under the hood

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have a class (eg "Collection") that knows what type it is working with (eg "DBType") and that class gets in the constructor a generic function (eg "Transform") that gets the subtype of DBType and returns an instance of another class based on this subtype. When the user calls collection's method with some parameters, collection can determine which subtype of DBType will be redirected to the transform function.

If I pass the subtype DBType to the transfrom separately, it works fine, but I'm stuck in the class. I can't seem to find a solution how should I do this. Maybe this is a limitation of typescript.

I made a simple example in the [playgroud](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEBUE0AUFEGUCwAoALgTwA4FNTwPYC22AIvgMagC8oA3qAM5HYBcjqATgJYB2A5qAC+KDDlAB5VAAtsHMpRr1802Wx4BXQgCNZQkVlwBhfOp6pZ86nVDkTZ1ddunUazTo5C9aA6BIAhSxpoAEMOVC5ggBsAHgJiSwAyCRU5ClAk42cLCgA+AG4UFAAzU3Jw-B5QLgY40goACgATCjZ-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-vA-55nSKDouACASuAZZUgAcvAABi4hlsSxSlOUlScME55FPgHCEJRC62osaEqphCbMKO+EnBcVw3AZRkmWZXZIYuKRKjZao3ikDkEc5emgG5DDGaZ5nITR1mDrZpHgcFOmXGFEVRZ5lpUShfkJWqK4jFwRSgPU1RLg03TtO0hUAsMYwTFMoDwZeTbPO0JwAsGsFVCVZU1HaTxVTVdF1fVQJNS1iZcu1nUjN1AINcCzUdgJM1VUGJz4txMbRtw-DgD4NAZR59T0L6bBel6QgrGuro1ei+AANYoDtzVuLIh1iMdHCGZFp1KCkbAAIygzdyxrhuHWgI9L3IG9mBckcX24D9f2ZWdkZZBwbD0E4ZggwADJ4gi3QxFBMWYbp5DDYDPTJz7YnJ8AKUpqkaVpBZgNAZbiH4FKwNp3hiOAv3udFKM5FY-kGDVVBS6YT08Pgwo8FtyChuGp5JhAxiRJER56dE8gADSgGpPBS6Nww7Rw6hlCZ9QnaZbAWx1+IAgccriEKMW9iEYQRDESroS8iUW9lFkQGL-0S1LAD8oBlhNPAo9EFtS6q7Hw1Gu2DVYLXgHrBsuTwxuoWbojYPgJXO4Qyp1ysXuND72CYxdoBejwwTENdpMnG9O6PAXHZF-g+uG9cZdxZXBg1+FMeZQ3i8eU3vAt0KmNDyDABMADMN0D7noCI2aRyBCtopjxPpfl6b4Vz7XK+mcv6Or8szet5j+OMrjWME6AYGxNBCH3xL6eQEMXTMGprTUAsAOAcBMigIeEDIYpBgeieBiCOAoFPjhRoqDybkEpixd2yAgA) that should be enough. Thanks for the help.

Comment: the question is very hard to read, if you were able to give better variable names (particularly they should match the playground) would make it easier to understand.  From what I can tell you are using overloads for your transform function which doesn't play well with the `ReturnType` type. (it only gives the result of last generic) but there is almost certainly another way of accomplishing what you are trying to do.

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen Thanks, fixed.

Answer (score 0):

The root of the problem is that you are using `ReturnType<typeof transform>` and the transform function is both generic and has overloads.  `ReturnType` can't cope with either of these things which is why you are getting incorrect results.  The correct logic you are looking for is along the lines of:

```
type TranslateDoc<T> = T extends TSomeDoc ? SomeDoc<T>
                     : T extends TOtherDoc ? OtherDoc<T>
                     : T

// TEST TRANSFORM
function transform<T extends TSomeDoc | TOtherDoc | Partial<TCountDoc>>(doc: T): TranslateDoc<T> {
```

I don't think there is a way to get the `TCollection` to be generic as to what transform it is using, for this transform you can write the class like this:

```
// second generic isn't used, relies specifically on the transform function only.
declare class TCollection<Doc, Fn extends typeof transform = typeof transform> {
    constructor(transform: Fn);

    findOne<T extends Partial<Doc>>(doc: T): TranslateDoc<T>;
}
```

As far as I know there is no way to use something like higher order generics (passing the `TranslateDoc` generic to the class in a way that it's argument is specified by the class)

Comment: Thanks a lot, but I'm looking for a solution that takes into account the unique features of each collection. It's a pity that there is no way to associate a type with a generic function under the hood;

Comment: There's a feature request for HKT (Higher Kind Types) [#1213](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1213) as well as new but promising implementation gist [#40368](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1213).